# Why my date don't change according my timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I'm trying to make my data stay in Brazil's time zone, but every time I try to change it, when I give a console it shows the correct date, but as soon as I send it to my backend the date changes the timezone completely, I just need get today's date, but as there is a time zone, at 9 pm the day changes to the next day, what am I doing wrong? I tried this code here.

```js
let date = new Date();

//this simulates the time after 21:00, just change the 15 to the number of hours needed so that the time is like after 21:00 to test (now is 8 am in Brazil)
date.setHours(date.getHours() + 15);

date = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];

$('#date').append(date.toLocaleString("pt-BR"));
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="date">
</div>
```

Comment: *toISOString* returns the UTC date. Brazilian timezones have offsets of -2 to -5. If you are in the -5 timezone, then the UTC date will be +1 day starting from 7pm (i.e. midnight plus the offset, -5 hours). That's because when it's 7pm in the -5 timezone it's midnight UTC at the start of the next day.

Comment: @DanielaGross - This part: `date.setHours(date.getHours() + 15)` is how you advance the actual point in time to a new point in time that is 15 hours in the future.  It's not how you adjust for time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) will give you the *UTC* time as an ISO string.

If you want to get your local date as an ISO string, this is easy to do, using the [`Date.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), [`Date.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) and [`Date.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) values.

We create an array with the [year, month, day] values in it, then use [`String.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [`String.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/join) to create the ISO date.

This will give the correct day of year in the local timezone.

```js
function getIsoDate(date) {
    const ymd = [ date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate() ];
    return ymd.map(s => (s + '').padStart(2, '0')).join('-');
}

console.log(getIsoDate(new Date()));
console.log(getIsoDate(new Date('2022-10-19T22:30:00')));
console.log(getIsoDate(new Date('2022-10-19T00:00:00')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

A simple hack that will also work is using [`Date.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) with the locale argument set to 'sv', this is because this language displays dates using the ISO format.

```js
function getIsoDate(date) {
    return date.toLocaleDateString('sv');
}

console.log(getIsoDate(new Date()));
console.log(getIsoDate(new Date('2022-10-19T21:30:00')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```